# Change height of a div in opera mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, opera

Im having a problem while changing the height of a div on Opera mobile, on other browser it works fine.

Im using a plan and simple `$('div').height(newheight)` but it's not changing, I believe this is a bug but there must be a workaround because Jquery Mobile is resizing the whole page.

Do you know what is this workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues for all of the sites I've built, and do indeed believe it's a bug in the mobile browser. The only way I've found to fix it is actually playing with the width/height in the SMS plugin markup, but unfortunately it will mess up how it appears on the other browsers.

Two solutions I've found: option one is to wait, since Opera is switching over to web-kit, option two is to plug in a simple alert jQuery script that detects if a user is browsing with Opera, and notifies them to use a supported browser instead (ie Firefox, Safari). It will be along the same code block as what I use for anything below IE 9:

```
 if ( $.browser.msie ){
if($.browser.version == '6.0')
{   
  // page redirect and alert for upgrade
  alert("... REQUIRES YOU TO UPGRADE YOUR WEB BROWSER For enhanced security and features on this website, please download Internet Explorer 9");
}
else if($.browser.version == '7.0')
{    
  // page redirect and alert for upgrade
  alert(".... REQUIRES YOU TO UPGRADE YOUR WEB BROWSER For enhanced security and features on this website, please download Internet Explorer 9");
}
else if($.browser.version == '8.0')
{   
  // page redirect and alert for upgrade
  alert("... REQUIRES YOU TO UPGRADE YOUR WEB BROWSER For enhanced security and features on this website, please download Internet Explorer 9");
}
```

}
});

Sorry that I don't have the exact code match you'll need, I just haven't had time to do it yet, but you'll want to replace the *browser.msie* with whatever the markup is for m.O